# Finding the minimum value

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, math, dynamic-programming

I can't begin to understand how to approach this problem. Can someone help me to just point me in the direction as to how I can approach it?

**N** tasks are given and there are **M** workers that are available. Each worker can takes different times to complete each task. The time taken by each worker for every task is given. At any time only one task can be worked on by only one worker. But the condition is once a worker has stopped working, he can't work on any task again. I want to find out what is the minimum time required to finish all the tasks. Here's an example-

M = 3 
N = 4 {T1, T2,T3,T4} 
No of days required by each worker (W<sub>i</sub>) for each task (T<sub>i</sub>) -

[image]

There are many ways to finish the task, some of them are -

1. All the tasks are done by the W1 ===> total time taken = 1+2+2+3 = 8
2. All the tasks are done by the W2 ===> total time taken = 3+1+3+2 = 9
3. All the tasks are done by the W3 ===> total time taken = 1+1+6+6 = 14
4. T1,T2,T3 done by W1 and T4 done by W2 ===> total time taken = 1+2+2+2 = 7
5. T1,T2 done by W1 and T3,T4 done by W3 ===> total time taken = 1+2+6+6 = 15
6. T1,T2 done by W3, T3 done by W1 and T4 done by W2 ===> total time taken = 1+1+2+2 = 6

There are more possible ways but the one that gives the smallest time taken is the 6th one (also shown in the picture below).

[image]

I was just able to understand how to do it when the number of workers are only 2. I did it this way -

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int N=4,M=2;

int main()
{   
    int i,j,min=INT_MAX;
    
    int sum,sum1;
    
    int w0[N] = {1,2,2,3};
    int w1[N] = {3,1,3,2};
    
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        sum=0;
        sum1=0;
        for(j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            sum+=w0[j];
            sum1+=w1[j];
        }
        for(j=N-1;j>=i;j--)
        {
            sum+=w1[j];
            sum1+=w0[j];
        }
        
        if(sum<sum1)
        {
            if(min>sum)
                min = sum;
        }
        else
        {
            if(min>sum1)
                min = sum1;
        }
    }
    
    cout<<min;
    
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to explain it using another table below -

[image]

But this way I can only find min value for 2 workers. I need help to to understand the approach for more than 2 workers.

Can there also be a DP solution possible for this?

Comment: What you can do there is to create a matriz in wich you can find the lowest value of each [i][j].

Comment: Do you have to complete the tasks in the order they are given or can you reorder them?

Comment: @Joni no tasks can't be reordered

Comment: @Carlos1232 do you mean smallest time of each worker? How will that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I can think to solve this is using recursion. I would implement this by having a list of unusable workers and a running sum passed to each call, and a global variable of minimum value.

This would also work best if you had a matrix of values. So like `matrix[0] = {1, 2, 3}; matrix[1] = {3, 4, 5}`. I haven't hardcoded a matrix in a while so please forgive me if the syntax is a little off.

So, using global variables for the matrix this would look something like

```
int matrix[m][n];
int runningMinimum = INT_MAX; //set the runningMinimum to max so any value compared will be lower
void minimum(int i, vector<int> bannedWorkers, int currentWorker, int sum){
    //test the end condition here
    if (i == n-1){//last column
        if (sum < runningMinimum){runningMinimum = sum;}
        return; //we want to return at the end, whether it's found the new lowest value or not
   
    //if we're not at the end, we need to move one step to the right for all possible workers
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++){//For each worker
        
        //check to see if the worker is no longer allowed to work
        bool isBanned = false
        for (int k = 0; k < bannedWorkers.size(); k++){
            if (bannedWorkers[k] == j) isBanned = true;
        }
        if(!isBanned){
            if (j == currentWorker){
                minimum(i+1, bannedWorkers, currentWorker, sum+matrix[j][i])
            }else{
                vector<int> newBannedWorkers = bannedWorkers; //Make sure to copy to a new vector
                newBannedWorkers.push_back(currentWorker);
                minimum(i+1, newBannedWorkers, j, sum + matrix[j][i])
            }
        }
    }
    return; //after we've checked every option we want to end that call
}
```

This is a rough, untested idea but it should give you a solid start. Hope it helps!

Comment: This is a good way, but your solution is assuming that order of ordering of workers, i.e it is strictly making the 1st worker to work first and then 2nd and then 3rd. the workers can be reordered in anyway

Comment: So for example if matrix[0] = {1,2,2,3} and matrix[1] = {3,1,3,2} then it is giving the correct result. But if we make matrix[0] = {3,1,3,2} and matrix[1] = {1,2,2,3} then it fails bcoz it is strictly following the order that W0 must work before W1. While in this case W1 must work first to complete task 1-3 and then W0 must finish task 4. The workers can be reordered on anyway. Any idea how to consider all the possible ways?

Comment: It should be able to process in any order. Just make sure to call it for all possible starts. e.g.
```
int main(){
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
        vector<int> bannedWorkers;
        minimum(0, bannedWorkers, j, matrix[j][0])
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah my bad, I forgot to change the currentWorker while calling them.

Comment: But this recursion is taking a lot of time. I wonder if we can somehow use dynamic programming to save the values we already calculated to use them later when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best approach if the number of workers is large, but easy to understand and implement I think. I would:

1. get a list all the possible combination with repetition of W, for example using the algorithm in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/combinations-with-repetitions/ . This would give you things like [[W1,W3,W2,W3,W1],[W3,W5,W5,W4,W5]...
2. Discard combinations where workers are not continuous (loop through the lists counting the times each worker appears in total and the times it appears continuously, if its different then discard the list)
3. Use the filtered list of lists to check times using the table and keep the minimum one

A possible way to discard lists could be

```
bool isValid=true;
for (int kk = 0; kk < workerOrder.Length; kk++)
    {    
        int state=0;
        for (int mm = 0; mm < workerOrder.Length; mm++)
        {
            if (workerOrder[mm] == kk && state == 0) { state = 1; } //it has appeard
            if (workerOrder[mm] != kk && state == 1 ) { state = 2; } //it is not contious
            if (workerOrder[mm] == kk && state == 2) { isValid = false; break; } //it appeard again
        }
        if (isValid==false){break;}
    }
```

Comment: Yeah it is easy to understand, but checking all the possible combinations with repetition will take a lot of time (Summation n+r-1Cr) which for as smaller values as n=10 checks more than 1.5k times.