# How to Solve Assignment Problem With Constraints?

Tags: algorithm

Assume there are N people and M tasks are there and there is a cost matrix which tells when a task is assigned to a person how much it cost.

Assume we can assign more than one task to a person.

It means we can assign all of the tasks to a person if it leads to minimum cost.
I know this problem can be solved using various techniques. Some of them are below.

- Bit Masking
- Hungarian Algorithm
- Min Cost Max Flow
- Brute Force( All permutations M!)

Question: But what if we put a constraint like only consecutive tasks can be assigned to a person.

```
    T1   T2   T3
P1   2    2    2
P2   3    1    4
```

Answer: 6 rather than 5

### Explanation:

We might think that , P1->T1, P2->T2, P1->T3 = 2+1+2 =5 can be answer but it is not because (T1 and T3 are consecutive so can not be assigned to P1)

```
P1->T1, P1->T2, P1-T3 = 2+2+2 = 6
```

How to approach solving this problem?

Comment: is the logic easy to code where more people and tasks are there?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62593556/2034787

Comment: @user3386109 I don't think you're right.  Without the constraint, you can assign each job to the lowest cost person.  With the constraint, half-way through the list you are on a particular person, having used up a set of people, considering at every step whether to switch or not to the remaining.  Try assigning 100 tasks to 30 people and your intermediate data structures have billions of options in them.

Comment: @btilly Yes, I was distracted by several things in the question, and didn't recognize the problem (without the constraint) for what it really is: simply choose the minimum for each task.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this problem using [ILP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming).

Here is an OPL-like pseudo-code:

```
**input: 
two integers N, M        // N persons, M tasks
a cost matrix C[N][M] 

**decision variables: 
X[N][M][M]     // An array with values in {0, 1}
               // X[i][j][k] = 1 <=> the person i performs the tasks j to k 
                              

**constraints:
// one person can perform at most 1 sequence of consecutive tasks
for all i in {1, N}, sum(j in {1, ..., M}, k in {1, ..., M}) X[i][j][k] <= 1

// each task is performed exactly once
for all t in {1, M}, sum(i in {1, ..., N}, j in {1, ..., t}, k in {t, ..., M}) X[i][j][k] = 1

// impossible tasks sequences are discarded
for all i in {1, ..., N}, for all j in {1, ..., M}, sum(k in {1, ..., j-1}) X[i][j][k] = 0

**objective function:
minimize sum(i, j, k) X[i][j][k] * (sum(t in {j, ..., k}) C[t])
```

I think that ILP could be the tool of choice here, since more often that not scheduling and production-planning problems are solved using it.
If you do not have experience coding LP programs, don't worry, it is much easier than it looks like, and this problem is rather easy and nice to get started.

There also exists a stackexchange dedicated to this kind of problems and solutions, the [OR stack exchange](https://or.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

This looks np-complete to me.  If I am correct, there is not going to be a universally quick solution, and the best one can do is approach this problem using the best possible heuristics.

One approach you did not mention is a constructive approach using A* search.  In this case, the search in would move along the matrix from left to right, adding candidate items to a priority queue with every step.  Each item in the queue would consist of the current column index, the total cost expended so far, and the list of people who have acted so far.  The remaining-cost heuristic for any given state would be the sum of the columnar minima for all remaining columns.

I'm certain that this can find a solution, I'm just not sure it is the best approach.  Some quick Googling shows that A* has been applied to several types of scheduling problems though.

Edit:  Here is an implementation.

```
public class OrderedTasks {

private class State {
    private final State prev;
    private final int position;
    private final int costSoFar;
    private final int lastActed;
    
    public State(int position, int costSoFar, int lastActed, State prev) {
        super();
        this.prev = prev;
        this.lastActed = lastActed;
        this.position = position;
        this.costSoFar = costSoFar;
    }

    public void getNextSteps(int[] task, Consumer<State> consumer) {
        Set<Integer> actedSoFar = new HashSet<>();
        State prev = this.prev;
        if (prev != null) {
            for (; prev!=null; prev=prev.prev) {
                actedSoFar.add(prev.lastActed);
            }
        }
        for (int person=0; person<task.length; ++person) {
            if (actedSoFar.contains(person) && this.lastActed!=person) {
                continue;
            }
            consumer.accept(new State(position+1,task[person]+this.costSoFar,
                    person, this));
        }
    }
}

public int minCost(int[][] tasksByPeople) {
    int[] cumulativeMinCost = getCumulativeMinCostPerTask(tasksByPeople);
    Function<State, Integer> totalCost = state->state.costSoFar+(state.position<cumulativeMinCost.length? cumulativeMinCost[state.position]: 0);
    PriorityQueue<State> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((s1,s2)->{
        return Integer.compare(totalCost.apply(s1), totalCost.apply(s2));
    });
    State state = new State(0, 0, -1, null);
    for (; state.position<tasksByPeople.length; state = pq.poll()) {
        state.getNextSteps(tasksByPeople[state.position], pq::add);
    }
    return state.costSoFar;
}

private int[] getCumulativeMinCostPerTask(int[][] tasksByPeople) {
    int[] result = new int[tasksByPeople.length];
    int cumulative = 0;
    for (int i=tasksByPeople.length-1; i>=0; --i) {
        cumulative += minimum(tasksByPeople[i]);
        result[i] = cumulative;
    }
    return result;
}

private int minimum(int[] arr) {
    if (arr.length==0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Not valid for empty arrays.");
    }
    int min = arr[0];
    for (int i=1; i<arr.length; ++i) {
        min = Math.min(min, arr[i]);
    }
    return min;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    OrderedTasks ot = new OrderedTasks();
    System.out.println(ot.minCost(new int[][]{{2, 3},{2,1},{2,4},{2,2}}));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is very similar to:
[Finding the minimum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62604843/finding-the-minimum-value/62606476#62606476)

Probably not the best approach if the number of workers is large, but easy to understand and implement could be

1. get a list all the possible combination with repetition of workers W, for example using the algorithm in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/combinations-with-repetitions/ . This would give you things like [[W1,W3,W2,W3,W1],[W3,W5,W5,W4,W5]
2. Discard combinations where workers are not continuous

```
bool isValid=true;
for (int kk = 0; kk < workerOrder.Length; kk++)
    {    
        int state=0;
        for (int mm = 0; mm < workerOrder.Length; mm++)
        {
            if (workerOrder[mm] == kk && state == 0) { state = 1; } //it has appeard
            if (workerOrder[mm] != kk && state == 1 ) { state = 2; } //it is not contious
            if (workerOrder[mm] == kk && state == 2) { isValid = false; break; } //it appeard again
        }
        if (isValid==false){break;}
    }
```

3. Use the filtered list of lists to check times using the table and keep the minimum one